# C# WebApi forwarding requests to another domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

We would like to forward all our C# WebApi traffic from domain A to domain B:

So for example:

```
GET https://www.billiving.com/api2/v1/invoices
routed to:
GET https://api.billiving.com/v1/invoices

POST https://www.billiving.com/api2/v1/invoices
routed to:
POST https://api.billiving.com/v1/invoices
```

etc.

- Everything needs to be forwarded including payload, headers etc.
- A configuration solution through **web.config** would be preferred.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don’t think you can redirect to different domain on application level this will happen on the server then  you can decorate your actions with both routes

Comment: I think you can do it somehow with URL rewrite.. just not sure about how to write that expression.

Answer (score 0):

By default Browser security restricts cross domain or cross origin api calls which is called as CORS
You can enable it by two ways one is using JSON Padding which JSONP and other is using Enable CORS

1. Using JSONP - using this your json data will be embedded in javascript and that way it is enabled through cross origin calls- you need to amend the data type from json to jsonp in this case
   the setting can be applied in webapi config class
   var jsonPObj = new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
   config.Formatters.Insert(0, jsonPObj);

Please note you need to install below package for jsonp
install-package WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp
2) Enable CORS
here you can enable particualr or call api calls and particualr HTTP verb or all using below setting in webapi config
EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:64298/EmployeeAuth.html", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);

Please note you need to install below package for above setting
install-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

Hope this helps!